# Renaming a repeated observation in SAS

Tags: sas

so I've been trying to figure out how to rename the ID variable in SAS (I made a dummy dataset to attempt this, see below)

```
DATA trial;
input hno $ y;
datalines;
a 1
a 2
a 3
a 4
b 3
b 5
cd 5
cd 6
cd 1
;
run;
```

and what I need to do is have all `a=1`, `b=2`, `cd=3` and so on, but the code would need to be transferrable to a dataset with ~30,000 observations all with varying ID's. I've been playing around with first.id and last.id but to absolutely no avail. Can anyone help?

Thank you in advance!

EDIT
So to clarify, I need code that produce the output:

    `a 1 1
    a 2 1
    a 3 1
    a 4 1
    b 3 2
    b 5 2
    cd 5 3
    cd 6 3
    cd 1 3`

where the third column there is the ID variable that increases by one for each unique hno value

Comment: Your question isn't very clear. Are you trying to have a sequential number for each unique value of the first variable in your dataset?

Comment: Yea exactly that. So there's a ID variable say, and it's made from the hno variable, and everytime there's a new hno value it would add 1 to the ID number. I need the dataset to have look like this afterwards:

`hno y ID
a 1 1
a 2 1
a 3 1
a 4 1
b 3 2
b 5 2
cd 5 3
cd 6 3
cd 1 3`

etc. Also, apologies in advance as I'm new to this site and don't know how to put it into a readable format!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you data are sorted by HNO this will encode HNO to an index.  RENAME in SAS usually refers to objects like variables, data sets, etc.

```
DATA trial;
   input hno $ y;
   datalines;
a 1
a 2
a 3
a 4
b 3
b 5
cd 5
cd 6
cd 1
;
   run;
data trial2;
   set trial;
   by hno;
   if first.hno then id + 1;
   run;
proc print;
   run;
```

If your input aren't sorted you created and index ID data set using PROC SUMMARY and the add the ID with a KEYed SET.

```
DATA trial;
   input hno $ y @@;
   datalines;
a 1 a 2 b 3 b 5 cd 5 cd 6 a 3 a 4
cd 1
;
   run;
proc summary nway data=trial;
   class hno;
   output out=index(drop=_type_ _freq_ rename=(_level_=id) index=(hno)) / levels;
   run;
proc print;
   run;
data trial2;
   set trial;
   set index key=hno/unique;
   run;
proc print;
   run;
```

[image]

Comment: Oh my word, I cant believe it was that straight forward! Honestly, thank you so much!!

Answer (score 0):

You can also try the `format`

```
proc format;
    value $ cn
    'a' = 1
    'b' = 2
    'cd' = 3
    ;
run;

DATA trial;
    input hno $ y;
    *format hno $cn.;
    id = put(hno, $cn.);
datalines;
a 1
a 2
a 3
a 4
b 3
b 5
cd 5
cd 6
cd 1
;
run;
```